# Why to exclude .js from PATHEXT for global node.js commands on windows

Tags: windows, node.js

Wanted to understand the pattern for .cmd files of globally installed node.js modules. Using grunt.cmd (located at %appdata%/npm) as an example:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt" %*
)
```

More specifically,

1. Why do we need the IF statement? Is it supposed that grunt.cmd is located somewhere outside of %appdata%/npm folder and this location may contain node.exe? Or it is assumed that %appdata%/npm itself contains node.exe? In which case it can be possible?
2. If there is no node.exe in the same folder as grunt.cmd file, then why do we need to exclude .js extension from PATHEXT environment variable?

Simply put, if someone could explain the whole idea behind this pattern I would be grateful as I did not succeed in looking for the explanations on the web so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're trying to look for an .exe but if it's not found on the path then we are looking for another .cmd file. In this case node.exe vs. node.cmd.

We don't want to find a node.js file, however.